# How to print columns if only a specific values is matched in a Linux?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a sample.txt file like this:

```
abc shk ansjc
def xyz dkksk
ghd ssk jshhd
djsh xyz dsoop
ssd swl jsjdl
```

I want to print column1 & column2 but column2 can be printed if only the content is matching with "xyz", so the output will be as follows.

```
abc
def xyz
ghd 
djsh xyz
ssd
```

This is what I tried so far,

```
awk '$2 == "xyz" { print $1,$2 }' output2.txt || awk '$2 != "xyz" { print $1 }'
```

Can anyone help me to get this output?

Comment: What's your field separator? One tab or multiple spaces?

Comment: @Cyrus it a one whitespace

Comment: `awk '$2!="xyz"{print $1}; $2=="xyz"{print $1,$2}' file`?

Answer (score 7):

Here is another POSIX complaint `awk` solution:

```sh
awk '{print $1 ($2 == "xyz" ? OFS $2 : "")}' file

abc
def xyz
ghd
djsh xyz
ssd
```

Comment: Also goes using the `comma`: `{print $1, ($2=="xyz") ? $2 : ""}`

Comment: Yes `awk '{print $1, ($2 == "xyz" ? $2 : "")}' file` works too but it leaves a trailing whitespace after 1st column.

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, you could try following.

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",$1,($2=="xyz"? OFS $2:"")ORS)}' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '{printf("%s%s\n",$1,($2=="xyz"? OFS $2:""))}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `printf` function of `awk` to print the values in current line(as per OP's need). In it firstly printing 1st field, then while printing 2nd value, checking condition if 2nd field is `xyz` then print space with $2 followed by new line else only print new line.

Answer (score 5):

With an `awk` implementation that allows manipulation of `NF` (ex: `GNU awk` and `mawk`):

```sh
$ awk '{NF = $2=="xyz" ? 2 : 1} 1' ip.txt
abc
def xyz
ghd
djsh xyz
ssd
```

You can also use `awk 'NF = $2=="xyz" ? 2 : 1'` since the expression will evaluate to *true*.

Comment: ++ but please mention this is gnu-awk only

Comment: @anubhava I checked with `mawk` and it worked too.. which is why I mentioned `awk that allows manipulation of NF`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest with `awk`:

```
awk '$2=="xyz"{print $1,$2; next} {print $1}' sample.txt
```

or

```
awk '{ if($2=="xyz"){print $1,$2} else {print $1} }' sample.txt
```

Output:

```
abc
def xyz
ghd
djsh xyz
ssd
```

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([^ ]+ xyz).*/\1/; t; s/ .*//'
```

Or more portably:

```
sed -E -e 's/^([^ ]+ xyz).*/\1/' -e 't' -e 's/ .*//'
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using `grep` with an optional group:

```
grep -o '^\S\+\( xyz\)\?\b' file
```

Or extended regexp

```
grep -oE '^\S+( xyz\b)?' file
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitspace chars
- `( xyz\b)?` Optionally match a single space and `xyz` followed by a word boundary `\b`

Output

```
abc
def xyz
ghd
djsh xyz
ssd
```